# Aren't there Christmas Hats this year?

Tags: discussion

Once other reason I was tempted to set up this account when I saw my bro was having multiple Christmas Hats to show off...

Aren't there any of those this year?

Comment: @Undo It's not really a duplicate of that - that's a declined feature request for how to run WinterBash this year.

Comment: Awesome. I really hope they do have..to get at least one had :D or to watch how hats bash goes on..

Comment: You can reuse the hats from last winterbash, take [Anna](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/155160/anna-lear) and [Tim](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/50049/tiny-tim) for example.

Comment: That's like so old hat @ShaWizDowArd.

Comment: Hats?! I thought this year was cats!

Comment: It's only December 5! Patience, grasshopper...

Comment: @Laura :D well in my town, folks are on pre-Christmas from October (right after Halloween) so patience for hats is something quite big :D